# While giving a space i am getting 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Tags: ios, web-services, swift, nsurl

i have 3 params in my NSURL object as i am passing in my webservice.
I am getting 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' while i am passing 'space' in one of my param.

### Code Below

```
     println("viewDidLoad contact name \(contactName)")// i am giving Space here like 'James '
    // println(countryCode)
    // println(townCode)



    var resultPage=false
        let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: "<URL>/searchContactsJSON?searchString=\(contactName)&towCode=\(townCode)&couCode=\(countryCode)") //I am getting error in this line....
```

If i am not giving a space in parameter than it is working fine...

Can someone please help me with above issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use .stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

```
"http://www.domain.com/?z=your string".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!  // "http://www.domain.com/?z=your%20string"
```

Answer (score 4):

The docs said:

> **Return Value:** An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the URL string was malformed, returns nil.
>   Discussion
>
> This method expects URLString to contain only characters that are allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be properly percent escaped. Any percent-escaped characters are interpreted using UTF-8 encoding.

So if you pass a whitespace to NSURL, it will produce nil, beacuse it is a malformed string.